# Ansible insert line after match

Tags: text, ansible

I'm trying to insert a line in a file after it matched the regex for the last time.
It's actually adding the line but at the end of the file.

```
  tasks:
  - name: add to ansible hosts file
    lineinfile:
      dest: "hosts"
      insertafter: '^\[ansible_ssh_host\]'
      line: " test ansible_ssh_host=172.0.0.3"
```

I want it to be added after the last line containing "ansible_ssh_host"

Destination file

```
ansible-server ansible_ssh_host=172.0.0.1
template-server ansible_ssh_host=172.0.0.2

[tag_ansible-servers]
ansible-server

[tag_template-servers]
template-server
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`'^\[ansible_ssh_host\]'` means search for a line that begins with `[ansible_ssh_hosts]`, but none of your lines actually start with that. You need a `regexp` which matches anywhere in the line.

Try this:

```
- name: add to ansible hosts file
  lineinfile:
    dest: "hosts"
    insertafter: 'ansible_ssh_host='
    line: " test ansible_ssh_host=172.0.0.3"
```