# Ansible - Insert new line after matched line using insertafter not working

Tags: linux, ansible

I have a simple playbook, trying to add a new line, after another line, but only if the line exists, in a zone file (RHEL, firewalld config file) using ansible 2.9. The target server is RHEL 7.9. I can't get the playbook to properly match the line. Right now, when running it, the playbook appends the line to the EOF.

I have tried using regex to no avail either, it still adds the line to the EOF. I have attempted many different variations including checking out the documentation and nothing works.

Here is the playbook (i've update it to make it easy for others to test):

```
---
- name: update firewalld
  hosts: rhel-08-dev
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
 
tasks:
- name: Add IP x.x.x.x to admin.xml
   lineinfile:
      backup: yes
      path: /etc/firewalld/zones/admin.xml
      insertafter: '<source address="192.168.7.0/24"/>'
      firstmatch: yes
      state: present
      line:  '<source address="192.168.16.0/24"/>'
```

I also checked out the following links as well:

[Ansible insert line after match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090254/ansible-insert-line-after-match)
[How to insert new lines after a specific empty line in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71954208/how-to-insert-new-lines-after-a-specific-empty-line-in-linux)

```
For reference, the file before:
[zone]
<source address="192.168.4.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.5.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.6.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.7.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.18.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.23.0/24"/>
[zone]

The file after
[zone]
<source address="192.168.4.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.5.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.6.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.7.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.16.0/24"/>   <---- I need to add the line here
<source address="192.168.18.0/24"/>
<source address="192.168.23.0/24"/>
[zone]
```

Comment: Please [edit] and make the above a [mre] as no one can guess just from your description what the original file looks like and what is the exact result you get. Also please check your yaml as it is not valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice to meet you.

Your playbook is working properly, but the only thing I want to mention it here according to the ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-insertafter):

```
If specified regular expression has no matches, EOF will be used instead
```

It seems `insertafter` does not have correct value.

Comment: I guess that's really what I am trying to figure out, I know that the regular expression is not matching (therefore it's adding the line to the EOF, however, I am trying to figure out what regexp I can use to match the line: '<source address="192.168.7.0/24"/>'?

Comment: I was using the wrong tool for the job it seems, thanks for pointing out the simple fact that if the expression fails, it uses EOF.